# Saving document scans as PDF using Office Lens

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, onedrive, ios

I have Office Lens (version 2.22) on my iPhone Xs.

I can't seem to save documents that I scan as PDF files. Office Lens saves them on OneDrive as JPG files and there are no settings anywhere that I could find.

Is there a way to save them as PDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OfficeLens offeres 4 different ways to scan something

- Whiteboard
- Document
- Business Card
- Photo

If you select the "Photo" mode, the result will be a JPG file, which by its very nature will not be easy to convert to PDF.

If you select the "Document" mode, OfficeLens will try to recognize the text and save it in a text format, which can easily be converted to PDF on a PC. Some elements of the original may not make it into the result though, like logos and non-text elements.

If OfficeLense cannot recognize the text, the result of a "Document" scan may still be a JPG.

But when you select where to store the result, the list includes "PDF". If you select that option, the image will be in a PDF file.

For more information about OfficeLens on iPhone, please refer to [this Microsoft Support article](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/office-lens-for-ios-fbdca5f4-1b1b-4391-a931-dc1c2582397b), which has screenshots and step by step instructions.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

too many words... Here's what you need to do:

1. Define at least one page from the pile of photos as a "Document" (icon at the top of photo allows you to select the type). If there are no "document" pages in the bunch, it will not allow you saving PDF. That's famous MS's user-friendliness.
2. Clicking next, select PDF. By default it sends to onedrive. But if you hold the option with a finger, then you can choose a local storage (fixed location in device/documents)
3. don't forget to rename
4. save - real, fine looking multipage PDF will be created.

Unfortunately, on Galaxy device/documents is not accessible from Skype, so you may have to move it somewhere, like SD-storage location, where Skype can pick it up.